# Hibernate : Downloading a file saved in PostgreSQL database as bytea

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am working in a Spring-MVC application in which I am saving documents in the database as a bytea. I am able to successfully save it into the database. Now I would like to retrieve the data stored in PostgreSQL column as a bytea, in a file. I am also saving the filename, so I can give the same fileName and the user can download. I have code to download a normal file which works, but I don't know how to make the bytea column as a file so user can download it.

Here is the code :
Attachments model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "attachments")
public class Attachment {


    @Id
    @Column(name="attachid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "attach_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "attach_gen",sequenceName = "attach_seq")
    private int attachid;

    @Column(name = "filename")
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "uploaddate")
    private Timestamp fileUploadDate;


    @Column(name = "attachmentdata")
    private byte[] attachment;

    // getters and setters ommitted
}
```

Controller code till now to download :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/download/attachment/{attachid}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getAttachmenFromDatabase(@PathVariable("attachid") int attachid, HttpServletResponse response){
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        try {

            // Below object has the bytea data, I just want to convert it into a file and send it to user. 
            Attachment attachment = this.attachmentService.getAttachmenById(attachid);

           // FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
            //org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inputStream,response.getOutputStream());

            response.flushBuffer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Spring's [FileCopyUtils](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.0.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html) to help.

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""+ attachment.getFileName() +"\"");
    response.setContentLength(attachment.getAttachment().length);

    FileCopyUtils.copy(attachment.getAttachment(), response.getOutputStream());
```

`Content-Disposition` can be `inline` or `attachment`, depending on whether you want the browser to display the content inline, or force a download.

From a security standpoint, you should serve inline user-uploaded content from a different domain (not subdomain), such as `exampleusercontent.com` for `www.example.com` and use the anti-XSS security headers, especially `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`

You should also wipe any location meta data from uploaded JPEGs.

Comment: Thanks man, this looks good, will try tomorrow and let you know and accept your answer once done, can you please check this related question, that would be super awesome, thanks.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674790/hibernate-single-out-a-column-containing-binary-data-which-shouldnt-be-loaded

Comment: @WeareBorg ya you need to use a one2one relationship w the file data or  use javassist and lazy loading on that property. i've seen the answer on SO before but can't find it right now

Comment: Yes, I am looking for lazy loading specifically on that property, but I cannot find it. If you have any luck finding it, please let me know, trying your solution now.